# Why doesn't the Sort method of my Linked List work?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to implement a sort method for a Singly Linked List. The method is suppose to go through the list, compare a pair of nodes, and place one of these at the front if needed. It uses two other methods: - Remove() (removes a specific node from list)
                        - InsertFront() (Insert a new node at the front of the list.
Both of these methods work by themselves and everything compiles.

```
    public Link remove(String lastName)
{
    Link current_ = first_;
    Link prior_ = null;
    Link found_ = null;
    while (current_ != null && current_.lastName.compareTo(lastName) != 0)
    {
        prior_ = current_;
        current_ = current_.next;
    }
    if(current_ != null)
    {
        if(prior_ == null)
        {
            found_ = first_;
            System.out.println(current_.next.lastName);
            first_ = current_.next;
        }
        else if(current_ == last_)
        {
            found_ = last_;
            Link hold_ = first_;
            first_ = prior_;
            first_.next = current_.next;
            first_ = hold_;
        }
        else
        {
            found_ = current_;
            Link hold_ = first_;
            first_ = prior_;
            first_.next = current_.next;
            first_ = hold_;
        }
    }
    return found_;
}

    public void insertFront(String f, String m, String l)
{
    Link name = new Link(f, m, l);
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Adding first name");
        first_ = name;
        last_ = name;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Adding another name");
        Link hold_ = first_;
        first_ = last_;
        first_.next = name;
        last_ = first_.next;
        first_ = hold_;
    }
}
```

I have tried to fix it but I always run into two different problems:

1. It works but does not insert the link back in.

   ```
       public void Sort()
   {
   Link temp_;
   boolean swapped_ = true;
   while (swapped_ == true)
   {
       swapped_ = false;
       Link current_ = first_;
       String comp_ = current_.lastName;

       while (current_ != null && current_.lastName.compareTo(comp_) >= 0)
       {
           current_ = current_.next;
       }

       if (current_ != null)
       {
           temp_ = remove(current_.lastName);
           insertFront(temp_.firstName, temp_.middleName, temp_.lastName);
           swapped_ = true;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. I receive a Null Pointer Exception.

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java. lang. NullPointerException
   at List $ Link . access $000(List . java : 25)
   at List . Sort ( List . java:165)
   at main( java :79)
   ```

   Java Result: 1

DeBugging results in:

```
Listening on javadebug
Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint LinearGenericSearch.java : 28, reason: The breakpoint is set outside of any class.
Invalid LineBreakpoint LinearGenericSearch.java : 28
User program running
Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.
User program finished


    public void Sort()
        Link temp_;     
    boolean swapped_ = true;
    while (swapped_ == true)
    {
            Link current_ = first_;
            swapped_ = false;
            while (current_.next != null)
            {

                if((current_.lastName.compareTo(current_.next.lastName)) > 0)
                {
                    temp_ = remove(current_.next.lastName);
                    insertFront(temp_.firstName, temp_.middleName, temp_.lastName);
                    swapped_ = true;
                }
                current_ = current_.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong? Any advice on how to avoid this next time?

Answer (score 2):

In java you don't have to do all this manually!! Just use LinkedList, code for the

```
 compareTo()
```

by implementing

```
 Comparable Interface
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and call

```
 Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
 to sort the way how ever you want to.

Comment: please feel free to ask if anything is not clear.